# Do GCP Deployment Manager templates require a schema file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

Since the templates can store values themselves (in addition to receiving values from the configuration yaml file), is a schema required when we create a template?

If not, is the use of the schema just to enforce which values are required, and the type of values that need to be provided to the template?

**EDIT**
I'm referring to template schemas, not resource properties schema: https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/using-schemas

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Deployment Manager has a built-in schema for its templates. You do not provide your own schema. The format and values (or types of values) accepted are defined in the documentation.

Comment: @JohnHanley I believe you're referring to properties schema. This is different. It's the schema for the templates you create: https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/using-schemas

Comment: I have never included a template schema in my deployments.

Comment: @JohnHanley do you just use a yaml file, or do include a python/jinja file as well?

Comment: Just YAML. I use DM everyday and I like the product. Very easy to work with.

Comment: @JohnHanley indeed :) what I'm doing now it's a bit overkill to use templates (just practice), but Google suggests learning about using templates for when the infrastructure becomes too complex. Check some Qwiklabs for DM, it's worth it.

Comment: I am preparing for Google certification this month. Check out my Qwiklabs profile https://www.qwiklabs.com/public_profiles/d4b344a7-3ed6-44a4-abe1-5918d9a02434

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184778/discussion-between-pedro-gordo-and-john-hanley).

Comment: @JohnHanley: It seems you have answered this question. Can you post your answer in the answer box so that the community can benefit from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Deployment Manager does not require that you specify a schema, but you can create one for specific use cases. I use Deployment Manager often, and I just use the standard YAML syntax for my deployments.

For those interested in learning more:

[Cloud Deployment Manager: Using Schemas](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/using-schemas)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old, but it's wrong. Question was about templates, not configs. If you create a template (.jinja) and import it from config (.yaml) during deployment using gcloud, it DOES require a .jinja.schema file for each imported .jinja.

Schemas are used by gcloud during packaging of your deployment, they are not required if you use plain yaml (no imports=no schema), they are also not required if you deploy directly using API.